# checkout / clone multiple branches from my git server

Tags: git, git-branch, git-worktree

I have this scenario on my git server :

```
git branch -a
```

gives output:

```
  common_data
* master
  shared_data
```

How do I check out branches shared_data and common_data at the **SAME** time into separate local folders:

```
working_directory/common_data
working_directory/shared_data
```

on my local workstation ? I have read numerous posts but somehow I don't get how to use the work_tree for this.

Thanks

GT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use git's `worktree` feature.  You only need to clone the repository once:

```
git clone myserver:myrepo.git
cd my repo
```

Then you can use `git worktree` to checkout branches into specific directories. For example, to check out your `feature/widget` branch into the `../myrepo-widget` directory:

```
git worktree add ../myrepo-widget feature/widget
```

Or maybe your `testing` branch into the `../myrepo-testing` directory:

```
git worktree add ../myrepo-testing testing
```

Alternately, you can just clone the original repository multiple times:

```
git clone -b master myserver:myrepo.git myrepo
git clone -b feature/widget myserver:myrepo.git myrepo-widget
git clone -b testing myserver:myrepo.git myrepo-testing
```

These two mechanisms are going to be functionally identical in most ways.  The second option requires more storage space, but most git repositories are small enough that the extra space is inconsequential.